# ATI Radeon HD 5970 Display numbering issues

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have 2 computers on which i have ATI Radeon HD 5970 graphics card installed. There is 1 VGA out and 1 DVI out in it.

When I connect my VGA out to a monitor on my 1st computer, it shows it as display 1 and when I connect my DVI out to a monitor it show it as display 2 (I am using extended display). When I do the same thing on my 2nd computer it shows just the opposite. The VGA out shows as display 2 and the DVI out shows as display 1.

Is it a problem with the drivers or the hardware? (because the graphics card on both is exactly the same)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. I've edited your post, if you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert or edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a driver issue at all since your extended desktop is working and working well simultaneously.

Here's the solution:

- Right click on your desktop, go to `Screen Resolution`.
- Drag your Display two on the left side of one in the `Change the Appearance of your displays`.
- Click on `Display 2` , the one you dragged to the Left of `Display 1`.
- You will see a CheckBox on that page, `Make this my main display`.
- I am attaching a screenshot of the same. Hoping it will solve your problem.
- Other than that, it doesn't matter which is `1` or `2`, it's just how windows detects it during installation. If you disconnect both, connect the one you want as `1` and boot your computer, it will be tagged as `1`, then connect the other one, and it will be tagged as `2`. So it doesn't matter.

[image: Making display 2 a main display]